# Javascript update to HTML table cell (from thousands to millions)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I need to create some Javascript on my web report which converts table values to thousands or millions (eg divides or multiplies by 1000).

The trouble is that each value is 'clickable' (i.e. it is wrapped in an anchor tag).

Is this possible?

```
<table class="Table" >
<thead><tr>
  <th class="l Header" scope="col">£000s</th>
  <th class="l Header" scope="col">Col1</th>
  <th class="l Header" scope="col">Col2</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="l Data">   My Data Row </td>
  <td class="l Data">   <a class=nums href="javascript:MyFunc();">  11,372,397</a></td>
  <td class="l Data">   <a class=nums href="javascript:MyFunc();">  11,344,327</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

**edit**

I am using IE6.   basically the aim is to have a 'thousands' and a 'millions' button so that the values of the table can become 11,372k or 11.4m etc...

Comment: Im not understanding your question, could you go in more detail

Comment: I am tempted to downvote just b/c you mentioned ie6 :-(

Comment: "I am using IE6." Traitor you are.

Comment: lol - well we don't really have a choice!  IE6 is company standard!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

```
$(function (){
    $.each($('.nums'), function () {
        $(this).html(Number($(this).html().replace(/,/g,"")) /*your math here*/);
    });
});
```

In response to your edit:
Since I'm bored I wrote this piece of working code for you, round and insert ',' as you see fit.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="Table" >
<thead><tr>
  <th class="l Header" scope="col">£000s</th>
  <th class="l Header" scope="col">Col1</th>
  <th class="l Header" scope="col">Col2</th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="l Data">   My Data Row </td>
  <td class="l Data">   <a class="nums" href="javascript:MyFunc();">  11,372,397</a></td>
  <td class="l Data">   <a class="nums" href="javascript:MyFunc();">  11,344,327</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<input type="button" onclick="toMillions();"> 
<input type="button" onclick="restore();"> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function (){
        $.each($('.nums'), function () {
            $.data(this, "theValue", $(this).html());
        }); 
    });


    function toMillions(){
        $.each($('.nums'), function () {
            $(this).html(Number($.data(this,"theValue").replace(/,/g,"")) / 1000000 + ' million');
        });
    }

    function restore(){
        $.each($('.nums'), function () {
                $(this).html($.data(this,"theValue"));
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Many thanks Odge - I will look at this on Monday.  Quick question though - will this code work without an internet connection?  I need the code to work in offline mode as well..

Comment: You would have to supply the jQuery JS in another way, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would start thinking about document.getElementsByClassName('nums'), which will give you an array of your elements.  Something like this:

```
nums = document.getElementsByClassName('nums');
for (i in nums)
   nums[i].innerHTML = nums[i]+',000';i
```

This likely only works in newer browsers, though, so you may want to use a similar method in a javascript framework.  Jquery allows getting elements by classname with the selector

```
$('.nums')
```

Comment: Take a look at a cross-bwoser implementation here - http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/

Comment: should have said browser above, I appear to suffer mildly from a typing lisp :)

Comment: .getElementByClassName unfortunately doesn't work in IE8 (without workarounds) which I'd say is a pretty new browser.